# on buttonclick direct to url with grabbed querystring from inputbox

Tags: jquery, url, button, input, query-string

I have an input box and a button. When user types in a search keyword i want to grab that on button click and also direct to URL+ Keyword, with the keyword appended to the url as a querystring like this http://mysite.com/events.aspx?kwd=dance

How do i do that in javascript or jquery?

```
<input name="keyword" class="EventSearchBox" type="text" />
<input name="SearchButton" type="button" value="Search" /><br/><br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off turning your HTML into a `form`, with its `action` attribute pointing to `http://mysite.com/events.aspx` and its `method` attribute as `get`.

Then you should rename your `keyword` input box as `kwd`. Then you wouldn't need to use any JavaScript to get it to work.

However, if that's not possible for some reason...

#### jQuery

```
var keywordInput = $('input[name="keyword"]');
$('input[name="SearchButton"]').click(function() {
   window.location = 'http://mysite.com/events.aspx?kwd=' + encodeURIComponent(keywordInput.val());
});
```

#### Without jQuery

```
var keywordInput = document.getElementsByTagName('keyword')[0];
document.getElementsByTagName('SearchButton')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  window.location = 'http://mysite.com/events.aspx?kwd=' + encodeURIComponent(keywordInput.value);
}, false);
```

Remember that < IE9 doesn't support `addEventListener()`. You'll need to use `attachEvent()`.